# how to include ttk themes in nuitka compilation of python file

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, ttk, nuitka

I have a python file that uses tkinter. I have added the ttk Azure theme to make it look better. However I am not sure how to include this in the nuitka command to compile my program into a standalone app. In my python file, I import it with this:

```
self.root.tk.call("source", "azure.tcl")
self.root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")
```

Because of this I tried to use the --include-data-files command to include it in my nuitka compilation.

Currently the command I use is:

```
python -m nuitka --enable-plugin=tk-inter --include-data-files=Logo.png=Logo.png --include-data-files=Icon.ico=Icon.ico --include-data-files=azure.tcl=azure.tcl --standalone main.py
```

The issue it throws is when i run the main.exe file is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Desktop\EVOLUT~1\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py" line 136, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\Desktop\EVOLUT~1\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py" line 29, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "./theme/light.tcl": no such file or directory
```

I think the issue may be that I need to include the whole folder that contains the file: Azure-ttk-theme-main, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also could anyone let me know how to change my command to create a single file .exe?

Comment: You should pack all the required files including ```theme/light.tcl```, which is used by the ```azure.tcl```.

Comment: Ok what is the command for that?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-4-program-distribution). You can use ```--include-data-files``` or ```--include-data-dir``` for the theme directory. Also don't forget you have the ```theme``` directory in the project directory.